# Mongoose update embedded document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
id: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, default: uuid.v1 },
    description: { type: String },
    period: [{
        id: { type: String, default: uuid.v1 },
        start: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        due: { type: Date },
        dueWarnByHours: { type: Number, integer: true },
        newnessByHours: { type: Number, integer: true },
    }],
```

i have an embedded mongodb database document like this. i tried updating it like the below one

```
WorkItem.update({ description: req.body.description},{period.rank: 3}, function(err, req) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.dir(reqWorkItemId + "Successfully removed the workItem from the database");
    });
```

but it isn't working how to update the embedded child part period->rank using mongoose

Comment: Is `description` the only field in your query? You can use the [positional operator `$`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-documents-in-an-array) in your update if you can have the period array as part of the query document i.e. `WorkItem.update({ "description": req.body.description, "period.rank": { "$ne": 3 } },{ "$set": { "period.$.rank": 3 } }, callback);`

Answer (score 2):

The following code will help you:-

```
var findQuery = { description: req.body.description, 'period.id' : someId};
WorkItem.update(findQuery,{$set:{'period.$.rank': 3}}, function(err, req) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.dir(reqWorkItemId + "Successfully removed the workItem from the database");
});
```

OR

```
 WorkItem.update(findQuery,{$set:{'period.$.rank': 3}}, function(err, req) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.dir(reqWorkItemId + "Successfully removed the workItem from the database");
});
```

**NOTE:- This will only update the first object of period array.**

Comment: Period array will have multiple objects or only one object ?

Comment: See the comment on your question, something like that you have to add in your find query, to make it work.

Comment: thank you i fixed it. based on your answer @Shrabanee

Answer (score 2):

```
WorkItem.update({ id: d }, { description: req.body.description, $set: { 'status.0.rank': req.body.status.rank } },
        function(err, numRowsAffected, raw) {
            if (err) return console.error(err);
            if (numRowsAffected > 0) {
                console.dir("reqWorkItemId" + "Successfully removed the workItem from the database");
            } else {
                console.log("fail");
                //res.send(500, { error: 'carrier not updated' });
            }
        });
```

This one works for me